# get post metadata depending on scroll position - wordpress/php

Tags: javascript, php, wordpress

I'm trying to build a custom newsfeed on my wordpress page.
I would like to have a static div on top, displaying the date of the post on the current scroll-position. 
How could I manage this in general? The best would be without plug-ins, since I have a very unsorted selfmade theme.

Thank you for reading, and maybe answering
Schnurbert

[image: explaining image]

Comment: Please visit: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask
What did you try? What do you have so far?

Comment: Hey there, since I only know about javascript "scroll-position" and the php get_metadata stuff, I haven't done anything yet, that's why I'm asking..